# how to use regular expression using the data attributes?

Tags: jquery, regex, html

I have one more small question I am using data-rule-range="[14,30]" for range in my html5 form. I am using multistep form plugin of jquery stepy which uses jquery validate. How can i use the field from using only alphabets. I can use something like data-regex???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTML5 attribute [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) will work on modern browsers:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" />
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7FqMh/)

---

If you want backwards compatibility and more flexibility for form validation, I suggest [ParsleyJS](http://parsleyjs.org/).

Comment: I tried using parsley but in this multistep form I was not able to do it. That's why i used the jquery validate